# Gaussian blur script in GIMP

Tags: gimp, script-fu

I am new to GIMP and scripting. I would like to know how to apply Gaussian blur for a layer using script. I could not find any simple example describing my requirement. I am using GIMP version 2.10.4. Please let me know how to apply Gaussian blur for a layer. Thanks.

```
(let*   (
(newimage (car (gimp-image-new 192 192 0)))
(newlayer (car (gimp-file-load-layer 0 newimage "D:\\t.png")))
(clayer (car (gimp-layer-copy newlayer 1)))
)
(gimp-image-add-layer newimage newlayer 0)
(gimp-image-select-color newimage CHANNEL-OP-REPLACE newlayer '(0 0 0))
(gimp-context-set-foreground '(9 77.9 95.3))
(gimp-edit-fill newlayer FOREGROUND-FILL)


(gimp-image-add-layer newimage clayer 0)
(gimp-image-select-color newimage CHANNEL-OP-REPLACE clayer '(0 0 0))
(gimp-context-set-foreground '(255 255 255))
(gimp-edit-fill clayer FOREGROUND-FILL)

/// 
here I want to apply Gaussian blur. I couldn't find the script command for it.
```

//////

```
(gimp-selection-none newimage)
(gimp-display-new newimage)
```

Comment: Probably off-topic since there are better Stack Exchange sites for this, but you at least need to show what you tried. _If_ script-fu coding is on-topic, then show your research ("gimp script gaussian blur" yields lots of information including tutorials) and your code and tell us what didn't work for you.

Comment: I already searched and I couldn't find any plugin or script example

Comment: SO is about asking coding questions, but your question seems to be "show me how to write a script-fu script" which is not on-topic. Either show what you have tried along with an explanation of what didn't work, or take a step back and visit some tutorials to get a grounding in the problem you want to solve.

Comment: I have attached my script code

Comment: Are you looking for `plug-in-gauss-rle` as in http://oldhome.schmorp.de/marc/pdb/plug_in_gauss_rle.html Maybe https://twentymegahertz.wordpress.com/2017/01/10/gimp-script-for-bringing-out-detail-in-the-image/ among others.

Comment: Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

All the Gimp API is documented in Gimp itself. Go to `Filters>Script-fu>Console...`, and hit the `Browse...` button. This opens a dialog that lists all the functions on the left, and gives a description of the selected function on the right.

Use the search bar at the top to restrict the API list to potential candidates (`blur`, or `gauss`)

Hit `[Apply]` to copy a prototype of the selected function to the console window.

Two caveats:

- there is no one-to-one relationship between Tools and API functions
- in Gimp 2.10, most GEGL tools (especially those that introduce new function) have no API equivalent for the time being.